# Issue adding ribbon buttons directly to quick access toolbar

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon, command, commandbinding

I am trying to add a Ribbon Button directly to the Quick Access Toolbar by using the CanAddToQuickAccessToolBarDirectly property. I have read in order to do this a command must be enabled on the button from this source (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2010/08/06/wpf-ribbon-basics.aspx#comments). When I add a command to the button it becomes disabled (grayed out).

Below is the XAML code snippet associated with the button, a visual representation of the issue and the associated CommandBindings for the RibbonBar:

[image]
(link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mV53U.png)

Any assistance with this issue would be greatly appreciated. This RibbonControlsLibrary.DLL is fairly new (released Aug. 2).

Answer (score 0):

Does the CommandBinding_CanExecute return true? Otherwise the command cannot be executed, hence the buttons (ribbonbutton and qat button) are disabled.